# how to disable swap from starting up on boot?

Tags: partition, fstab, swap

I don't want to disable the swap completely, I just don't want to start automatically on boot. What is the best way to do that ,should I execute the `swapoff` command or do I have to comment out swap line in the `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Comment the line out in `/etc/fstab` - you can always use `swapon -a` if you want to bring it online

Comment: please note after `swap -a` uncomment that line to have it mounted at boot again.

Answer (score 1):

Change the /etc/fstab line from:

```
/dev/sd1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

to:

```
/dev/sd1 swap swap noauto 0 0
```

and bask in afterglow.